# How to restrict the Applications access/ visibility in DevPortal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While we can control the visibility/ access to APIs in Publisher and DevPortal using **Publisher Access Control** and **Developer Portal Visibility**, how we can achieve the same for Applications?

I tried to high/ unhide some Applications based on the user logged in, but was not able to do it. Is there a way we can do this or is it available only for APIs?

Tried creating a set of roles and associate with Applications visibility but unable to find such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications are by default user-specific and It is not shared. If it is required, you can share the Applications between user groups[1].

If you are expecting to disable application creation for some users(or all users), follow the approaches here[2]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-application/sharing-applications/sharing-applications/

[2] [WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 disable application creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469826/wso2-apim-4-1-0-disable-application-creation)